# Reflect.getOwnMetadata is not a function in karma with latest Aurelia

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-runner, aurelia

After updating to the latest version of Aurelia (March update beta.1.1.4), I'm getting the following error every time I run karma tests:

```
Error: Reflect.getOwnMetadata is not a function
Error loading C:/Software/myproject/test/unit/myclass.spec.ts
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has to do with the change of Aurelia from `core-js` to home-grown polyfills. The Reflect polyfill is missing and tests fail to run.

This problem is addressed in Aurelia navigation skeleton app by the following import statement in each unit test file:

```
import 'aurelia-polyfills';
```

I solved it by creating a `setup.ts` (or `setup.js` resp. to your language) file with just this statement, and then just listing it in `karma.config.js` at the first place.

for JS e.g.:

```
jspm  : {
  loadFiles: ['test/unit/setup.js', 'test/unit/**/*.js'],
  ...
}
```

for Typescript e.g.:

```
files: ['test/unit/setup.ts', 'test/unit/**/*.ts'],
...
```

Comment: Hey I followed the setup above and am getting a 404 on the aurelia-polyfills package.  I do have it installed and am on aurelia-polyfills@1.0.0-beta.1.0.1.  Any idea as to why its not locating the aurelia package?  I am using the above .js example

Comment: `jspm install aurelia-polyfills --dev` should fix that up.

Comment: @Mikhail - Just wondering if I am missing something, created the file and referenced it within the config, also updated polyfills but I am getting an error when trying to run "import 'aur....' is unexpected reserved word

Comment: I owe you a beer for posting this

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange :) You are welcome. A simple upvote is enough ;)