# Reflect.getOwnMetadata - Updating Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

[Reflect.getOwnMetadata is not a function in karma with latest Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775200/reflect-getownmetadata-is-not-a-function-in-karma-with-latest-aurelia)

I believe my issue to be the same as this, but I am unsure. I needed to update 'binding' from `aurelia-binding@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.5` to `aurelia-binding@^1.0.0-beta.1.3.0`, due to a bug fix within that release, since updating I recieve the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: TypeError: Reflect.getOwnMetadata is not
>   a function(…)

After a bit of research, mostly being linked back to the question above in one way or another, I had hoped their solution would solve mine however, `gulp watch returns: import 'aurelia...' unexpected reserved work`. Unsure what I am missing

I think the actual issue is with loading the following, seems to break here first

```
(function(System, SystemJS, require) {define(["npm:aurelia-templating-resources@1.0.0-beta.1.0.2/aurelia-templating-resources"], function(main) {
  return main;
});
})(System, System);
```

Comment: I would try to update aurelia-templating-resources to a newer version too.
I had some strange error messages when the different aurelia librarys where from different versions.

Maybe you should have a look at the latest update: http://blog.durandal.io/2016/03/23/aurelia-babel-6-and-jspm-update/
There has been a lot going on with aurelia.

Comment: To add to what I wrote before: you'll probably need to update all aurelia librarys if you start updating one.

Comment: Thanks updated everything and now its now keen on any @customElement or popover. Slowly working through these errors :-(

Comment: You need to poly fill the reflect API in your tests. If you look in the skeleton you can see that we do this in a setup.js file that is loaded first by karma.